# iPhone create html receipt email based on contents template file

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to send an HTML email receipt from the iphone. The receipt should have some dynamic data in it.

I would prefer to have a template .html file with {placeholders} in it that will be replaced by using something like this:

```
 strBody = [strBody stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:"{name}" withString:username]
```

But first I need to know how to load the contents of the file into a string so I can start replacing the placeholders.

How could this be done and will this work well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of situation I highly recommend Matt Gemmell's open-source [MGTemplateEngine](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/05/20/mgtemplateengine-templates-with-cocoa). With that you create a template file of named placeholders, and pass in a dictionary of replacements where each key matches one of the placeholders. It's very flexible. Check out the demo project for details on how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to add your .html file to your Xcode project, after that something like this should work:

```
NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"nameOfFile" ofType:@"html"];
if (file) {
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:file encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    if (html) {
        html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{title}" withString:@"foo"];
        html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{body}" withString:@"bar"];
        NSLog(@"%@",html);
    }
}
```